# How to export ksql table data to Mysql table with jdbc connector

Tags: mysql, apache-kafka, confluent-platform, connector, ksqldb

Is there any way to export data from KSQL to mysql table by jdbc connector??

I found out how to import mysql table data to Kafka cluster with KSQL. But it is not what I want.

```
docker run -d -p 127.0.0.1:8088:8088 \
-e KSQL_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS=my-cluster:9092 \
-e KSQL_LISTENERS=http://0.0.0.0:8088/ \
-e KSQL_KSQL_SERVICE_ID=kakaoblog_ksql \
-e somthing is be here... 
confluentinc/cp-ksql-server:5.3.1


docker run --net=host --interactive --tty \
confluentinc/cp-ksql-cli:5.3.1
```

https://www.confluent.io/hub/confluentinc/kafka-connect-jdbc
https://docs.confluent.io/current/ksql/docs/installation/install-ksql-with-docker.html
https://docs.confluent.io/current/ksql/docs/tutorials/clickstream-docker.html#ksql-clickstream-docker
https://docs.confluent.io/5.0.0/installation/docker/docs/installation/connect-avro-jdbc.html

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to, yes. What you need is a sink connector, rather than a source connector.  ksqlDB can run the connector for you.

This is an example of outputting data into ElasticSearch using ksqlDB: https://ksqldb.io/examples.html#create-an-elasticsearch-sink-connector

The JDBC connector docs can be found here: https://docs.confluent.io/kafka-connect-jdbc/current/index.html